# Tkinter not changing image on button press

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have loaded an image to tkinter label and that image is diplayed in that label.When i press the button i need to change that image.When the button is pressed older image is gone but the new image is not displayed
My code is

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = tk.Tk()

def change_pic(labelname):
 photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("demo.jpg"))
 labelname.configure(image=photo1)
 print "updated"

vlabel=tk.Label(root)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('cardframe.jpg'))
vlabel.configure(image=photo)
vlabel.pack()
b2=tk.Button(root,text="Capture",command=lambda:change_pic(vlabel))
b2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know if PIL is the same as Tkinter's PhotoImage. In Python, there's garbage collection and sometimes it doesn't do what we want it to do. What you need to do to get the image as a separate instance then apply that to the class, otherwise, Python collects your image instance. `image = Image.open("demo.jpg")` and `photo = PhotoImage(image)` together might work.

Comment: @PrestonHager tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following edits were made:

1. I have organised your code layout and simplified its
   syntax where possible. These are to make your code easier to read.
2. Commonly we make the PIL objects a subset/children of tk.
   So long it is a part of root (i.e. it is a child of the root
   or any of its child widgets), your PIL objects will work.

Your working code is shown below:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def change_pic():
    vlabel.configure(image=root.photo1)
    print "updated"

root = tk.Tk()

photo = 'cardframe.jpg'
photo1 = "demo.jpg"
root.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(photo))
root.photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(photo1))

vlabel=tk.Label(root,image=root.photo)
vlabel.pack()

b2=tk.Button(root,text="Capture",command=change_pic)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9):

In `def change_pic(labelname)`, you need to add `labelname.photo = photo1` to make sure `photo1` not being garbage collected.

```
def change_pic(labelname):
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("demo.jpg"))
    labelname.configure(image=photo1)
    labelname.photo = photo1
    print "updated"
```

**P.S.** Looks like both `labelname.photo = photo1` and `labelname.image = photo1` work.

Check this out for more details: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

> You can use the label to display PhotoImage and BitmapImage objects.
>   When doing this, make sure you keep a reference to the image object,
>   to prevent it from being garbage collected by Python’s memory
>   allocator. You can use a global variable or an instance attribute, or
>   easier, just add an attribute to the widget instance.

Comment: I wonder if there is such a known issue why it is not done inside configure function?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with one more line of code:

```
import tkinter as tk                        # I am using python 3 on windows so the tkinter is lowercased
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = tk.Tk()

def change_pic(labelname):
    global photo1                           # This is the only new line you need, I believe
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("demo.jpg"))
    labelname.configure(image=photo1)
    print("updated")                        # Again I'm using python 3 on windows so syntax may differ.
    root.update()                           # You don't need this statement in this case, but it never hurts

vlabel=tk.Label(root)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('cardframe.jpg'))
vlabel.configure(image=photo)
vlabel.pack()
b2=tk.Button(root,text="Capture",command=lambda:change_pic(vlabel))
b2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I believe that the code changes the image locally, so the **global** statement will change it on the project scope.